# Getting error `spawn ./gradlew ENOENT` when I run `tns build android`

Tags: nativescript

I'm starting with nativescript. I'm trying to build a hello world application to test it. However, when I run it, I get an exit status 127 for command not found.

Here is how I try to build:

```
[ahmed@localhost hello]$ tns build android
Executing before-shouldPrepare hook from /home/ahmed/PycharmProjects/hello/hooks/before-shouldPrepare/nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Skipping prepare.
Building project...
Gradle build...
spawn ./gradlew ENOENT
[ahmed@localhost hello]$ echo $?
127
[ahmed@localhost hello]$
```

If I run `tns doctor`, everything seems to be ok

```
[ahmed@localhost hello]$ tns doctor
✔ Getting environment information 

No issues were detected.
✔ Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and points to correct directory.
✔ Your adb from the Android SDK is correctly installed.
✔ The Android SDK is installed.
✔ A compatible Android SDK for compilation is found.
✔ Javac is installed and is configured properly.
✔ The Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed and is configured properly.
✔ Local builds for iOS can be executed only on a macOS system. To build for iOS on a different operating system, you can use the NativeScript cloud infrastructure.
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
✔ Component nativescript has 5.1.0 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-core-modules has 5.1.1 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-android has 5.1.0 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-ios has 5.1.0 version and is up to date.
[ahmed@localhost hello]$
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran `tns install` to install dependencies. That solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying several things, the one that worked fort me, was:

1. `ns clean`
2. `ns install`